# Java 8 sort Map<String, List<Double>>

Tags: sorting, dictionary

How to sort a Map > according to average of all the values in the list  using Java8 streams?

I couldn't figure out how to collect the sorted map to another instance of map. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is the code that I tried

```
Map<String,List<Double>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Double>>();
LinkedList<Double> list1 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(12.5,45.67));
map.put("1",list1);
LinkedList<Double> list2 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(13.5,49.67));
map.put("2", list2);
LinkedList<Double> list3 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(10.5,9.67));
map.put("3", list3);
LinkedList<Double> list4 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.5,40.67));
map.put("4", list4);
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, List<Double>>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, List<Double>> arg0, Entry<String, List<Double>> arg1) {
                return (int)(((LinkedList<Double>)arg1.getValue()).stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum() - ((LinkedList<Double>)arg0.getValue()).stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum());
    }
});
System.out.println(map);
```

The output I get is still the same Map with out sorting. The expected output here is a map with the entries in this order

```
<"2", list2>
<"1", list1>
<"4", list4>
<"3", list3>
```

### Edit:

Here is the solution I got to

```
Map<String,List<Double>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Double>>();
LinkedList<Double> list1 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(12.5,45.67));
map.put("1",list1);
LinkedList<Double> list2 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(13.5,49.67));
map.put("2", list2);
LinkedList<Double> list3 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(10.5,9.67));
map.put("3", list3);
LinkedList<Double> list4 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.5,40.67));
map.put("4", list4);

LinkedHashMap<String,List<Double>> orderedMap = new   LinkedHashMap<String,List<Double>>();
Iterator<Entry<String, List<Double>>> iterator = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, List<Double>>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, List<Double>> arg0,
                                            Entry<String, List<Double>> arg1) {
        return (int)((((LinkedList<Double>) arg1.getValue()).stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum() - ((LinkedList<Double>)arg0.getValue()).stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum()));
    }
}).iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Entry<String, List<Double>> next = iterator.next();
    orderedMap.put(next.getKey(), next.getValue());
}
System.out.println(orderedMap);
```

I am not happy with this solution. Is there a precise and better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you add some code? Do you want to collect the stream elements into a special map implementation, like a `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: @stholzm : I output I need is sorted map and I do not want any special map implementation.

Comment: `sorted()` returns a stream and does not modify the original map.

Comment: I tried collect() method with Collectors.toMap() on the stream to get the sorted map. Even that did not work. I get an error saying can not convert hashmap to list.

Comment: A `SortedMap` still needs a comparator for its keys, but you want to compare entries by their value? I do not think this is going to work, or I still misunderstand you. Maybe it helps if you try to come up with the expected result (and add it to your question), but I am giving up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparator doesn’t do the job you want, or at least not always. It works only if all the lists have the same size because you are comparing the sum not the average values for each list. I created a new Comparator based on lists average values and simplified the code. Below is my code:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String,List<Double>>> byAverange = 
 (Entry<String,List<Double>> o1, Entry<String,List<Double>> o2)->
     {
       return  ((Double)o2.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).average().getAsDouble())
                .compareTo(
                o1.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).average().getAsDouble()); 
            };

LinkedHashMap<String, List<Double>> ordered =  new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(byAverange).forEach(entry -> ordered.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
System.out.println(ordered);
```

output:

```
{2=[13.5, 49.67], 1=[12.5, 45.67], 4=[1.5, 40.67], 3=[10.5, 9.67]}
```

hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks Mario Cairone. Your code looks precise and easy to understand.